# Swiper.JS slidesPerView not working - sometimes shows more, sometimes to few

Tags: swiper.js

I tried using both the webcomponent as well as let's say plain old JS approach and in every case slidesPerView does not work right:

```
<div class="swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide" v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item.id"><!-- i use vue and wanted to avoid using the vue part of slider since that seems to become deprecated soon --> 
       {{item.id}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
 const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
         speed: 400,
         spaceBetween: 3,
         slidesPerView: 5,
         width:700
      });
```

and I see 7 slides. And if I set slidesPerView to 'auto' I see one slide only

My imports are:

```
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import Swiper, { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';
```

I must be doing sth wrong as this is so simple. Any ideas someone?

Comment: I figured out a soltuion: Use <div class="swiper-slide" style="width:fit-content"> which seems to enable swper to make slidesPerview correctly and also seems to prevent swiper  from blowing up the parent container.

Comment: Hey, have you ran into any trouble with customizing the css for swiper in vue 3, if so have you found any solutions to it?

Comment: Hey Still using vue2 at the moment. Had quite some issues with loop mode, starting with the slide i wanted select initially and the blow-up. In the end I opted for a subset of functioanlity, wrapped the whole thing in a wrapper component that jsut exposes what I found to be working well for me. Best of luck

Comment: almost funny, that this seems to be not part of the documentation anymore, but `swiper-slide` has a default css rule of `width: 100%` and if you want to show multiple slides at once, eg. `slidesPerView: 'auto'` you need to set the css to `width: auto`